# modificar contenido de una celda con js

Tags: php, javascript, html

Saludo compañeros, llevo dias intentando modificar el contenido de una celda al presionar un boton que esta en la misma fila... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero cambiar el texto de la columna observacion cuando presiono el boton de SI o NO 
ayuda...

este mi codigo de la tabla
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

```
 <tbody id="myTable">
                <?php
                mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
                //Generamos consulta.
                $sql = "SELECT  concat(a.nombre, ' ', a.Apellido), Seccion, r.IdRegistro
                        From registro r
                        INNER JOIN alumno a  on r.Identidad_Alumno = a.Identidad
                        where  IdGrado = '$grado' and IdModalidad = '$modalidad' and Seccion ='$seccion' and Anio = '$anio'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $datos =  $ver[0] . "||" .
                        $ver[1];
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $ver[0] ?> </td>
                    <td hidden><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td>

                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="asiste()" id="si">SI</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="inasiste()" id="no">NO</button>
                    </td>
                    <td id="des">Realizar Asistencia</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Podrías indicar tu código html al menos.

Comment: dame un momento

Comment: he intentado de muchas maneras y no logro hacerlo ayudaa

Comment: Por favor publicá tu código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: quiero generar una funcion para que cambiar el texto de la columna observacion cuando presione el boton si o no

Answer (score 1):

no te compliques, casi lo tienes, lo unico que debes hacer teniendo en cuenta que en el `While` del `PHP` que nos muestras generas tu tabla es:

- A cada `<td class="observacion">` tiene que agregarle un `ID`, este debe ser unico, por ejemplo podria ser el `ID` de la tabla (PK)
- En el elemento `<td>` donde pones los `button` asignas una funcion, cierto?, pues a esta funcion debes pasarle como parametro un `ID`, por ejemplo quedaria algo asi: `onclick="asiste(1112)"`

Hasta aquí la explicación, ahora un pequeño ejemplo, los ID me los invento, es cosa tuya decidir de donde sacarlos o que poner.
Yo lo sacare de la query, suponiendo que existe el campo `ID`
Por mi comodidad usare JQuery.

---

**Ejemplo**

```
<tbody id="myTable">
   <?php
      mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
      $sql = "SELECT  concat(a.nombre, ' ', a.Apellido), Seccion, r.IdRegistro, a.id From registro r INNER JOIN alumno a  on r.Identidad_Alumno = a.Identidad where  IdGrado = '$grado' and IdModalidad = '$modalidad' and Seccion ='$seccion' and Anio = '$anio'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
      while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
         $datos =  $ver[0] . "||" . $ver[1];
   ?>
    <tr>
       <td> <?php echo $ver[0] ?> </td>
       <td hidden><?php echo $ver[2] ?></td>    
       <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="asiste('div<php? echo $ver[3] ?>')" id="si">SI</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="inasiste('div<php? echo $ver[3] ?>')" id="no">NO</button>
       </td>
       <td id="div<php? echo $ver[3] ?>">Realizar Asistencia</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
 </tbody>
```

**JS**

```
function asiste(id){
   $("#"+id).html("Necesita asistencia...");
}

function inasiste(id){
   $("#"+id).html("No necesita asistencia...");
}
```

Espero te sirva. Suerte!

Comment: me funcionó tu idea, y lo apliqué a otras propiedades de las celdas

Comment: Genial, si te sirvió como respuesta recuerda marcarla como solucion

Answer (score 0):

No veo necesario que lo que tengas que editar en la columna obvervaciones dependa de dar click en los botones, si no podrías hacerlo directamente desde esa casilla, recreandolo parecido a esto:

```js
// target a los inputs con la clase observacion
// usando spread operator para hacerlo iterable(ES6 feature)
const $inputs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('observacion')]

// listener al evento click de cada input
// para recobrar el borde y remover readonly (mientras se edita)
$inputs.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.border = 'inherit'
    this.removeAttribute('readonly')
  })
})

// listener al evento blur de cada input
// para volver a quitar el border cuando se sale del focus del input
// y volver a darle el attributo readonly
$inputs.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.style.border = 'none'
    this.setAttribute("readonly", true);
  })
})
```

```css
.observacion {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">nombre</th>
        <th scope="col">asistencia</th>
        <th scope="col">observación</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-success">SI</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger">NO</button>
        </td>
        <td class="observacion"><input type="text" class="observacion" readonly value="foo"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-success">SI</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger">NO</button>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="observacion" readonly value="bar"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```